# Yii - Cdbcriteria - Choose where operator between conditions with relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I got the following problem.
I Want to show only the taks of a person who have inserted the task itself or is responsible for the task, for this, I have the following database schema:

table Funcionario (table of employees) = id, name, etc...

table TarefasGerais (table of tasks) = id,id_funcionario (who inserted it), etc...

table TarefasResponsaveis (table of responsible employes) = id, id_tarefa (tarefas gerais id), id_funcionario (employee id)

in my model's search method I did the following:

```
    $criteria->with = array('Responsaveis' => 
        array('condition' => 'Responsaveis.id_funcionario = ' . Yii::app()->user->dados->id));
    $criteria->condition = 'id_funcionario_lancamento = ' . Yii::app()->user->dados->id;
```

but it generates the following SQL:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `tbl_tarefas_gerais` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_tarefas_gerais_responsaveis` `Responsaveis` ON
    (`Responsaveis`.`id_tarefa` = `t`.`id`) WHERE (id_funcionario_lancamento =
    3) AND (Responsaveis.id_funcionario = 3)
```

as you can see, it uses the "AND" operator, but I need it to use the "OR" operator in the where section.

I tried :

```
    $criteria->with = array('Responsaveis' =>
        array('condition' => 'Responsaveis.id_funcionario = ' . Yii::app()->user->dados->id, 'operator' => 'OR'));
```

but it didn't changed anything.

Does anyone have any idea of how to deal with ?

Cheers 0/

Answer (score 5):

Try `mergeWith` two criteria.

Sperate your logic into two criteria and merg them together

```
$criteria->with = array('Responsaveis' => 
    array('condition' => 'Responsaveis.id_funcionario = ' . Yii::app()->user->dados->id));
$criteria2->condition = 'id_funcionario_lancamento = ' . Yii::app()->user->dados->id;
$criteria->mergeWith($criteria2);
```

Full example:

```
$criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria2->addInCondition('startDate', array(null));
$criteria2->addBetweenCondition('startDate', date('Y-m-d'), '1950-01-01', 'OR');

$criteria3 = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria3->addInCondition('stopDate', array(null), 'AND');
$criteria3->addBetweenCondition('stopDate', '1990-01-01', date('Y-m-d'), 'OR');

$criteria3->mergeWith($criteria2);
```